# Trigger a button click when the space bar is pressed (Web Page)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button on my webpage that I needed to be triggered when the user clicks with the mouse but also when he hits the spacebar, is that even a thing?

HTML

```html
<div class="col-12 button small-button">
       <a onclick="generator()">
            <img src="icones%20web%20projeto.png" title="Descubra um novo artista" alt="New Image">
       </a>
</div>
```

JS

```
function generator() {
    var x= Math.floor((Math.random()*35)+1);
    console.log(x);
    document.getElementById('divImage').innerHTML='<img src="img/'+x+'.png">';
 }
```

Comment: Hi Isabela, yep it's a thing. You'l need an `onkeydown` (or `onkeyup`) event handler in addition to your `onclick` handler. You'll then determine which key was pressed ("space" vs "enter" vs "tab") and execute the same click handler.

Comment: Even if the user doesn't have a focus on the button? I mean, imagine the focus is on another element.  I'm asking this because if you have a focus on the button and press spacebar, the event click will be triggered,

Comment: @Ele, it seems (based on the provided HTML) that it's not a button in the traditional sense. Your comment does make a great point - using a button would just work. Isabela, here's a JSFiddle using a button: https://jsfiddle.net/2gxdshvt/ (which you'll see works with space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the use of any third-party libraries.

```js
document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        // add your code here.
        console.log('Space pressed');
    }
}
```

Or using `addEventListener()` method:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        // add your code here.
        console.log('Space pressed');
    }
});
```